# puzzle in probability, doors and passangers

Tags: probability

I was given this in a list of puzzles by my proba prof:

(4) Customers leaving a subway station can exit through any one of three gates. Assuming
that any particular customer is equally likely to select any one of the three gates, find
the probabilities of the following events among a sample of five customers.
(a). Two select gate A, two select gate B, and one selects gate C.
(b). All five select the same gate.
(c). All three gates are used

My take on this:

(a). Any singular possibility combination has proba $(1/3)^5$ in our case it would be: $(1/3)^2(1/3)^2(1/3)^1$ (2 for A, 2 for B, 1 for C)
(b). In this case, lets take the probability that they all g to door A, as above we obtain: $(1/3)^5$. But the question asks independently from a specific door. So it would ask : proba of the union that all go to A or B or C. Given each option is mutually exclusive (they cant all go to 2 door) it would be P(all A)+P(all B)+P(all C) => 3/243
(c). For this one, I find 6 alternative possibilities where they would take all 3 doors,  3 using: 3,1,1 and 3 using 2,2,1. How can I find this analytically, so if we expand the question to M doors and N passangers?

Comment: part a) is incorrect - We can pick which two go through door $A$ in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways, and which of the remaining go through door $B$ in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways, giving the net probability $3^{-5}\binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{3}{2}$. Your answer doesn't take the fact that different choices by individuals can give rise to the same net door leaving situation.

Comment: For part c), to count the number of valid configurations, let $x_i$ be the number of people that go through door $i$. Then $x_1 + \dots x_m = N$, and you're demanding that $x_i \ge 1$. This has standard solutions via the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method.

Comment: I understand now my error, it seemed strange to me the results did not depend on the possible combinations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your take on (1) would be correct if we wanted the first two passengers to choose $A$, the next two to pick $B$, and the last passenger to pick $C$. But there are other orders this could occur in.

(2) seems good, but note that $\frac3{243} = \frac1{81}$.

For (3), the (reworked) answer tells you what the probablility of 221 is. The probability of 212 and 122 are, of course, the same. Finally, you need to work out the probability of 311 the same way, and add those.

There are other ways to do (3). For instance, you can look at it this way: Given any one gate, there is a $(2/3)^5$ probability that none of the passengers will use that gate. That makes it an easy $3\cdot (2/3)^5$. Except that it doesn't.

Both the one where we counted the probability of no one going through gate $B$, and the one where we counted the probability of no one going through $C$ took into account the one possibility that all passengers choose gate $A$. That one possibility has therefore been counted *twice*, and we therefore need to subtract one. Same with doors $B$ and $C$. Therefore the final answer is $3\cdot (2/3)^5 - 3\cdot(1/3)^5$.

For generalisation of this method to solve (3), look up inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Thanks for the hing on how to generalize, I get how this works better now.